# How to make ubuntu-13.10-server installation writable?

Tags: server, permissions, usb-drive, iso, disk-image

I have downloaded and `dd`'d a thumb drive with the ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64.iso file (`sudo dd if=ubuntu-13.10-server-amd64.iso of=/dev/rdisk3`). Unfortunately, after the installation the thumb drive is not writable. `chmod`-ing the files do not work: the whole disk is viewed as a CD-ROM.

- Is it possible to make my non-writable USB thumb drive writable?
- Or are there any switches/flags to `dd` that would do the trick?
- Anything else that would do the trick?

Comment: can you post output of the "mount" command? maybe the drive is mounted as ro - might as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not writable, as it contains [ISO 9660](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) filesystem. A [separate tool](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/creating-an-ubuntu-live-usb-from-cd/) called "Startup Disk Creator" can be used for creating "live USB".

Open `System > Administration > Startup Disk Creator`, select your `.iso` and (USB) disk to use, and click `Make Startup Disk`.